# Why did the Lizard formula work better for Komodo?

Tags: marvel

In *Avengers: The Initiative*, Komodo's abilities stem from using Dr Curt Connor's lizard formula.

[image: Avengers; The Initiative #8]

In addition to regrowing her legs, she is shown to have more control over the change process than Connor's and does not suffer from the same personality issues as The Lizard.

Has a reason been given for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Komodo's origin is covered in more detail in *Avengers: The Initiative Special* - "The Real Thing".

Essentially, instead of it being a straight theft she had worked with Connors for some time before to perfect the formula for her DNA.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

in No Turning Back, Slott's Amazing Spider-Man story he pretty much states that The Lizard persona is all Curt Connors Anger and bitterness of his injury and lot in life made form so Komodo who is of a somewhat healthier mindset is pretty much one mind in both forms

Comment: Do you evidence for this you can [edit] in such as the quote/panel?

Answer (score -2):

Although no official reason has been given for this, it should be noted that this is not the first instance of something like this happening. When Cindy Moon became Silk after being bitten by the radioactive spider that turned Peter Parker into Spider-Man, she produced a natural web-shooting ability which Peter did not. Similarly, when Jennifer Walters was given a blood transfusion from Bruce Banner, she became She-Hulk, although much more in control; she retained her intelligence and could switch back and forth when desired, although she mostly chose to keep her Hulk form. This is in contrast to Bruce Banner's Hulk in the sense that when Bruce becomes angry, frustrated or hurt, he 'Hulks out' and goes on a rampage.

Comment: There was an official reason given, and I'm not sure what an exploration of the Hulks and Silks' origin has to do with anything. Also, FWIW, Peter did exhibit organic shooters a number of times, particularly around the first Raimi film, he got them in a story from the Spectacular Spider-Man vol. 2 #15-20 (2004), and lost them around One More Day / Brand New Day.